# My regex for replacing 'acronyms' does not work in sed, while it works elsewhere

Tags: regex, sed

I have tried this regex (in this example it should match "BMW" and "ALL") in other programs, where it does work:

```
$ sed -E 's/\b(?<![A-Z]\s)\b[A-Z]{2,}\b(?!\s[A-Z][A-Z])\b/REPLACED/gm;t;d' <<< "this BMW is ALL But"
```

I get this error message:

```
>>> sed: -e expression #1, char 60: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work in sed, and what the possible workaround is?

Comment: If you need a perl regex use `perl`, `perl -pe 's/\b(?<![A-Z]\s)[A-Z]{2,}\b(?!\s[A-Z][A-Z])/REPLACED/g' file`. Sed does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! That is exactly what I require!